# How to create and install all relevant font-metrics and fontmaps of a TrueType font on Linux for (pdf)TeX?

Tags: linux, fonts, truetype, texlive

Essentially I have found [this guide](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm), but it is for miktex, i need a guide for texlive on Debian/Ubuntu which will not pollute dpkg installed texmf.

I'm interested in converting TrueType font to be usable in (pdf)(La)TeX.

All the power google turn up just stuff f relating how to install microsoft fonts or do stuf on MikTeX.

I CANNOT USE XeLaTeX!!! I use pstricks and the font must be available in plain TeX! Otherwise my document looks inconsistent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare to enter a world of pain. I've been down this road recently and still haven't gotten correct output:

http://xpt.sourceforge.net/techdocs/language/latex/latex33-LaTeXAndTrueTypeFont/ar01s03.html
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/otfinst/

I've gotten further with otfinst.py, where "further" means "the fonts appear but the metrics are horribly horribly wrong (like overlapping glyphs, wrong)".

My suggestion: learn to love Computer Modern Roman. It shouldn't be this hard.